# Para onde aponta o Git pull?

Tags: git

Eu estava lendo a documentação do Git sobre pull e acabei ficando confuso:

Então vamos criar uma sequência hipotética:

1. Clonei o repositório
2. Fiz um `git branch` que mostra apenas o master.
3. O comando `git branch -a` mostra o meu branch local (que é o master) e os outros remotos.
4. Eu quero ter localmente o branch develop. Então faço `git checkout -b develop origin/develop`. Aqui aparece a minha dúvida. Quando fazemos `git checkout -b develop origin/develop` estamos puxando o braço develop remoto ou estamos habilitando localmente um braço develop que foi puxado no momento do clone? Observando essa parte da [documentação do git pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull), me parece que é o segundo cenário, pois essa é a justificativa do `git pull` antes de fazer um `pull da origin`.

   Update the remote-tracking branches for the repository you cloned from, then merge one of them into your current branch:

   ```
   $ git pull
   $ git pull origin
   ```

Ou seja, está parecendo que o `git pull origin`, vai puxar de um braço local que é origin/develop  mas que não é o develop que está no repositório central.

Então por isso temos que fazer um `git pull` para atualizar todas as imagens locais com o conteúdo remoto e depois fazer o pull origin develop para atualizar o meu develop local com o origin/develop que é local tbm.

Isso me deixa confuso pois de dentro do meu branch develop `git branch -vv` me mostra:

> develop bbfdft67 [origin/develop] ZF45: Modifications in the tables
>   and chart in FAQs - Take 3,

Então se o meu develop aponta para [origin/develop] eu não precisaria fazer `git pull` (como sugere a documentação) antes de fazer `git pull origin`, a não ser que eu quisesse atualizar todos os branches locais ("escondidos"). E se esse fosse o caso, se com o git pull atualizasse tudo, eu não precisaria fazer `git pull origin` de dentro do meu develop.

Então na verdade, de onde esta se puxando (ou atualizando dados) quando faço git pull?

Comment: O `git pull` faz um `git fetch` seguido de um `git merge`. Quando você específica qual o remoto, então ele não pega do padrão para aquele branch, mas do branch equivalente do remoto passado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *de onde está se puxando (ou atualizando dados) quando faço `git pull`?*

Ele sempre puxa os dados de algum *remote* (repositório remoto). Quando você não informa nenhum (ou seja, digita somente `git pull`), a [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) diz o seguinte:

> *Default values for  and  are read from the "remote" and "merge" configuration for the current branch*

Ou seja, ele usa as configurações de "remote" e "merge" do branch atual, e você pode vê-las usando `git config`.

Por exemplo, se o meu branch atual é o `master`, posso fazer o seguinte (para o comando abaixo usei o Bash do Linux, em um repositório qualquer - é só um exemplo, pode ser que o seu esteja diferente):

```bash
$ git config --list |grep master
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Ou seja, no meu caso, `git pull` puxaria as informações do *remote* (repositório remoto) chamado `origin`, e a opção de `merge` indica que ele é feito em `refs/heads/master`.

Para ver qual é o `origin`, basta rodar `git remote show origin`, que nas primeiras linhas ele mostrará as URL's de onde os dados são puxados. Ex:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://url.repositorio.com/projeto.git
  Push  URL: https://url.repositorio.com/projeto.git
```

Quanto a `refs/heads/master`, é um [*refspec*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) que aponta para o branch `master`.

Enão neste caso, `git pull` seria o mesmo que `git pull origin master`. Mas se meu branch atual fosse outro, e/ou se tivesse outra configuração de "remote" e "merge", então esses parâmetros é que seriam usados.

---

> *Quando fazemos `git checkout -b develop origin/develop` estamos puxando o braço develop remoto ou estamos habilitando localmente um braço develop que foi puxado no momento do clone?*

[Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/564389/112052) tem uma explicação detalhada sobre o que é `origin/develop`. De forma bem resumida, ele possui a informação sobre o branch `develop` do repositório remoto `origin`, mas é a informação que você obteve da última vez em que sincronizou com o `origin` (seja via `git pull` ou `git fetch`).

Isso quer dizer que `origin/develop` nem sempre estará atualizado (pode ser que o branch no *remote* tem novos commits e você ainda não puxou essas alterações). Se depois de clonar você não fez mais nenhum `pull` ou `fetch`, pode ser que ele esteja desatualizado.

Quando você faz um `pull` ou `fetch`, ele atualizará o `origin/develop`, e aí sim você pode rodar esse `checkout` sabendo que agora ele está atualizado de acordo com o *remote*.

Answer (score 1):

execute um `git remote -v` que ele vai mostrar a associação de onde vem os dados.

`origin` é um apelido que o `git` dá para um repositório remoto quando ele é clonado.

Answer (score 1):

> Quando fazemos git checkout -b develop origin/develop estamos puxando o braço develop remoto ou estamos habilitando localmente um braço develop que foi puxado no momento do clone?

Quando você faz um checkout -b está criando um branch localmente, o segredo do fluxo de trabalho está no push a partir desse branch local, que deve ser feito com:

```
git push --set-upstream origin develop
```

Eu dou um exemplo completo de criação de branch local https://analisedesistemas.wordpress.com/2018/06/27/git-branch-a-partir-de-outro-branch/