# Qual a diferença entre "git pull origin/branch" e "git pull origin branch"?

Tags: git

Quando eu preciso atualizar o repositório local, costumo executar o comando `git pull` ou `git pull origin/branch`.

O `git pull origin/branch` até onde entendo "puxa" o que tem na branch remota (o `origin` indica o repositório remoto), mas vi que `git pull origin branch` também funciona, e não entendi a diferença.

Parece que ambos atualizam o repositório local com o conteúdo da branch remota, mas por que tem essa variação?

Eles fazem a mesma coisa?

Answer (score 2):

`git pull origin/branch` funcionava em versões antigas do Git, mas hoje não funciona mais (dá o erro "*fatal: 'origin/branch' does not appear to be a git repository*").

> Não encontrei a versão exata em que parou de funcionar, mas [este comentário](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2883840#comment15719053_2883857) cita a versão **1.7.10.3**, que segundo [este commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26e5c5d09334d157bd04f794f16f6e338d50c752), é de 2012. Vale lembrar que na data em que escrevo esta resposta, a versão atual é **2.37.3**. Ou seja, faz muito tempo que não funciona mais.

Ainda sim acho que vale explicar a diferença entre `origin branch` e `origin/branch` (não somente para o `pull`, mas de forma geral).

---

## Branch remoto

`origin/branch` é o que [a documentação chama de "*Remote Branch*"](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) ("branch remoto"). Apesar do nome, é um branch que está no seu repositório local (também conhecido como "na sua máquina"), e o "remoto" quer dizer que ele está "ligado" a um branch no repositório remoto.

Um exemplo clássico deste tipo de branch é quando você clona um repositório.
Ao fazer algo como `git clone http://rep.url/projeto.git`, o Git baixa o repositório e cria algumas coisas para você:

- um *remote*: uma referência ao repositório remoto que você acabou de clonar, cujo nome padrão é `origin` (é possível mudar, claro, mas isso já foge do escopo da resposta)
- um *remote branch*: no caso, seria algo como `origin/master`. É um branch "local" (pois fica na sua máquina), mas que aponta para o branch `master` do repositório remoto `origin` (para ser mais exato, ele aponta para o mesmo commit que o branch `master` estava apontando no repositório remoto `origin`, no momento em que a clonagem ocorreu)
- um branch local: no caso, o branch `master`, que aponta para o mesmo commit que o `origin/master`

[image: "git clone" cria um remote branch]
<sup>Fonte: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/images/remote-branches-1.png</sup>

No exemplo acima, o commit `f4265` corresponde ao branch `master` no repositório remoto. Ao cloná-lo, o seu repositório local conterá o branch local `master` e o *remote branch* `origin/master`, ambos apontando para o mesmo commit.

Mas note que, embora inicialmente o `master` e o `origin/master` estejam apontando para o mesmo commit, eles não são a mesma coisa.
O `master` você pode alterar normalmente (criar commits, merge, rebase, etc). Já o `origin/master` só é alterado ao sincronizar os dados com o *remote*.

Por exemplo, se você alterou o `master` (fez várias alterações e commits), então agora ele aponta para um novo commit, enquanto o `origin/master` continua apontando para o commit no qual que ele estava na última vez que você o sincronizou com o *remote*.

Mais ainda, se outra pessoa atualizar o repositório remoto (por exemplo, alguém fez um `push` e você não ficou sabendo ou ainda não atualizou o seu repositório local), então o `master` muda no repositório remoto, mas o *remote branch* do seu repositório local (`origin/master`) **permanece o mesmo**:

[image: Se você não sincronizar com o remoto, origin/master não mudará]
<sup>Fonte: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/images/remote-branches-2.png</sup>

A imagem acima ilustra essa situação: alguém fez `push` no repositório remoto, criando dois commits que você ainda não tem localmente (`31b8e` e `190a3`). Mas como você ainda não sincronizou com o repositório remoto (não fez `git pull` nem `git fetch`), então o remote branch do seu repositório local (`origin/branch`) está desatualizado: ele ainda aponta para `f4265`.

Basicamente, o `origin/master` contém a informação da última vez que você "conversou" com o *remote* (neste exemplo, foi na clonagem do repositório). Para puxar as atualizações ocorridas no *remote*, você pode usar `git fetch` (que atualiza o `origin/master`, mas não o `master`) ou `git pull` (que [faz o `fetch` seguido de `merge`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/232250/112052), ou seja, atualiza tanto o `origin/master` quanto o `master`).

---

#### Sobre o `git pull`

É [mais que sabido](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292359) que isso:

```
git pull origin branch
```

É equivalente a isso:

```
git fetch origin branch
git merge origin/branch
```

Antigamente, quando `git pull origin/branch` ainda funcionava, ele basicamente pegaria o commit para o qual `origin/branch` aponta e puxaria essas alterações para o seu branch atual. Como nas versões atuais esse comando não funciona, acho que não faz mais sentido considerá-lo.

Já `git pull origin branch` faz primeiro o `git fetch origin branch` (ou seja, verifica se o *remote* `origin` tem alterações no `branch` e caso tenha, atualiza o `origin/branch`). Depois, com o `origin/branch` atualizado, ele faz o merge com o seu branch local.

Indo um pouco mais a fundo: segundo a [documentação de `git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull), muitos parâmetros são repassados para `git fetch`. Então `git pull origin/branch` acaba chamando `git fetch origin/branch`. Mas lembre-se que `origin/branch` é um branch local (embora ele esteja relacionado com um branch remoto, ele é local, está na sua máquina). E não faz sentido fazer `fetch` de algo que é local, já que o intuito deste comando é trazer as alterações do *remote* que você ainda não tem localmente.
<sup><palpite>Talvez por isso que esse comando passou a não funcionar mais?</palpite></sup>

Por fim, note que a documentação mostra os parâmetros que o comando aceita:

```
git pull [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>…]]
```

Ao fazer `git pull origin/branch`, estou dizendo que `origin/branch` corresponde ao `repository`. Mas como `origin/branch` não é um repositório (e sim um branch, como já vimos), isso explica a mensagem de erro ("*'origin/branch' does not appear to be a git repository*"). O fato de funcionar em versões antigas mostra - na minha humilde opinião - que a decisão de mudar este comportamento foi acertada, pois agora parece fazer mais sentido não aceitar um branch como repositório.

Já quando eu faço `git pull origin branch`, estou dizendo que `origin` é o repositório, e `branch` é o branch que quero atualizar (sendo mais preciso, a documentação cita que `refspec` pode ser várias coisas diferentes, mas o mais comum é usar o nome de um branch).

---

Quanto ao [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/398966#comment784012_399224) sobre `git reset origin master` funcionar, nas versões mais novas também dá erro. Estou usando a 2.37.3 e o erro foi "*fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree*". **Talvez** tenha funcionado para você por estar usando uma versão antiga (o que explicaria também o fato de `git pull origin/master` ter funcionado).

Já `git reset origin/master` funciona, pois `origin/master` é um branch, e neste caso ele funcionará normalmente, [como é com qualquer outro branch ou commit que passamos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325951/112052).

---

#### Resumindo

`origin/branch` é um branch. Ele tem características "especiais" (não posso mexer diretamente nele, pois ele só é atualizado quando sincronizamos os dados com o seu respectivo *remote*). Mas pode ser usado em outros lugares nos quais se espera um branch (como por exemplo `git log origin/branch` para ver seu histórico, ou `git show origin/branch` para ver seus detalhes, ou `git diff origin/branch outro_branch` para ver as diferenças entre ele e outro branch, etc).

`origin branch` são dois parâmetros: `origin` indica o repositório remoto e `branch` é o nome do branch. No caso do `pull` e `fetch`, indica que estou buscando atualizações daquele branch, no repositório remoto para o qual o `origin` aponta.

---

Ver também:

- [Differences between git pull origin master & git pull origin/master](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2883840)
- [git fetch + git merge origin/master vs git pull origin/master](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61211167)